# Copying and transfering cell contents from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

The pseudocode for a program I'm writing is as follow:

1. Activate Sheet1 - renamed 'Information'
2. To locate a specific word containing cell. E.g. "NAME"
3. Select the immediate cell next to the cell containing "NAME". (offset(1,0))
4. Copy the cell contents
5. Activate another sheet - 'Results'
6. Paste the copied contents in cell B2.

Idea is to locate a cell containing a variable, copy the cell contents next to it and transfer the copied results into another sheet.

Note that multiple variables are to be located and the cell content next to it are to be copied in the same sheet and transferred into a another sheet - Results for compilation.

I'm hoping to repeat this process for multiple sheets.

Can anyone please guide me along with the commands and methods with achieving this?

Much appreciated for sharing a more efficient method!

Comment: record a Macro and then substitute the `Activate`/`Select`/`ActiveXXX`/`Selection` pattern it heavily uses with fully qualified range references (i.e. instead of `ActiveCell.Copy` use `Worksheets("mySheetName").Range("myCellAddres").Copy` and the likes. If you get stuck come back with your code and its issues after carefully reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you know all the steps, and even the functions you need, now all you need to do is use a new site called "Google" , trust me, within 15 minutes you'll get all the info you need

Answer (score -1):

You are wanting something like

```
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = "NAME"
Set Rng = Worksheets("Information").Cells.Find(What:=FindString)
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.Offset(0,1).Copy Worksheets("Results").Range("B2")
End If
```

Some of that code needs to be tailored to better suit your needs, but I didn't want to do **all** your work for you.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any of the work.  SO professes to **not be a code writing service**.  Please help people that show some effort by posting actual code instead of pseudocode.  It devalues the site by answering questions that don't meet site standards.